# rails 4: Adding a class to a select tag

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, formbuilder, actionview

Trying to add a class to a select tag

```
<%= f.select(:ptype, options_for_select(TourParticipation::PTYPES, selected: "traveler", disabled: "Role:") , { :class => "widens" } ) %>
```

results in

```
<select name="tour_participation[ptype]" id="tour_participation_ptype"></select>
```

Why is the class not applied to my select tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget that before `html_options` is `options` hash. Try this:

```
<%= f.select(:ptype, options_for_select(TourParticipation::PTYPES, selected: "traveler", disabled: "Role:") , {}, { :class => "widens" } ) %>
```

See definition:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

Comment: The correct syntax would be: `<%= f.select(:ptype, options_for_select(TourParticipation::PTYPES, selected: "traveler", disabled: "Role:"), {}, class: "widens") %>`